# accessing androids auto correct facilities?

Tags: java, android, sms, prediction, autocorrect

Is there a way of using Android's auto correct / predictive text capabilities with a bespoke input method? I'd like to be able to access a list of the nearest words to the word entered, similar to what happens when we send a text. For example if I entered the string "hapy" I would get a list containing "happy", harpy", "hazy" ...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a yes.

And the place to start: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to.  First off, predictive text was only turned into a service with 4.0.  Before then it was just part of the keyboard, and most keyboards still implement their own I suspect.  Secondly, it would be optimized for typing mistakes, not voice mistakes.  Typing g instead of f is common (they're next to each other), doing it by voice is not.  It wouldn't work well.

But the built in voice to text behavior does return alternatives-  it returns an array list of possible texts.  That is your auto-correct.